# Center the logo (Vertical/Horizontal)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to find a way to center the logo + text. The image+text should be center vertically and horizontally.

I tried couple of things and now i have this html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>XXX</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:50px 0px; padding:0px; /* Need to set body margin and padding to get consistency between browsers. */
    text-align:center; /* Hack for IE5/Win */
    }
#floater    {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-120px;}

#Content {
    clear:both; 
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto; /* Right and left margin widths set to "auto" */
    text-align:center; /* Counteract to IE5/Win Hack */
    padding:15px;

    height:240px; 
    position:relative;
    }
#text-center{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Content">
<img src="logo_small.jpg" width="400" height="143">
<p id="text-center">Coming soon</p>
<p id="text-center">more text</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know anything related to html/css

Comment: add `margin: 0px auto;` in `#text-center`

Comment: I want to align the logo/text to center of the page (vertically/horizontally). the thing you mentioned removed distance between 2 p tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/CMfEH/

I used a variant of what's descriped in [Vertically Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).

Answer (score 0):

Vertically aligning content is typically a bad practice but can be achieved using
*EDIT*: had to switch up some css...

```
#Content {
        margin: 0px auto;
        ...
        height: 100%;
        }
#subContent {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        height:240px; 
        margin-top: -120px;
        }
```

And creating a `<div id="subContent">` div inside your Content parent div.